# MPI Scatter and Gather

Tags: mpi, scatter

I am working on a program that does matrix multiplication using MPI. Matrix A is broadcast to all the processes. Matrix B is transposed and then scattered among all the processes. So that A can directly be multiplied by each column of B. So far it is working, I obtained results from individual processes and they are correct. Now I am stuck at gathering all the results at the root process and displaying them.

> MPI_Scatter(&transpose_mat, num_cols2, MPI_INT, column2, num_cols2, MPI_INT, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

This is how I scatter the data among all the processes.

> column3 = mult(result, column2);

The function mult calculates the multiplication result and returns a column vector **column3**

```
if (rank == root)
    {
        MPI_Gather(&column3, 4, MPI_INT, &final, 4, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4;++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; ++j)
            {
                cout << final[i][j] << endl;    
            }
        }
    }
```

## And this is how I try to gather them back.

But it doesn't show any output, even though I am trying to print out **final[][]**

Could anybody explain me what is the issue ?

Comment: Isn't `MPI_Gather` a collective operation ?  In other words, shouldn't all processes in the communicator call it ?  It seems only your root process calls it.

Comment: Yes, thanks so now I took it out of the if statement, but the result is  the same. The data isn't gathered in the final matrix.

Comment: So now you want us to diagnose problems in code you're not showing us ?

Comment: Sorry. I should've posted the complete code. I have worked the solution now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, **MPI_Allgather()** worked for me.
**MPI_Gather()** wasn't showing anything but **MPI_Allgather()** collects data (column matrices in my case) from all the processes into a buffer (matrix in my case).